# Jenkins jacoco plugin empty report

Tags: maven, jenkins, jacoco

I have a project where I use Jacoco to calculate the code coverage.
I use maven configuration like here :

http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/maven/creating-code-coverage-reports-for-unit-and-integration-tests-with-the-jacoco-maven-plugin/

With Jenkins, I run "mvn clean install test". It generates the report in the /target/site/jacoco-ut/ folder. If I open the index.html file, I see this :

[image]

But when I open JaCoCo Coverage Report in jenkins job, I see this :

[image]

It says that every test cover 0% of the code. I don't understand why I don't have the same result that I have in the html report.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.5.201505241946</version>
            <executions>
                <!--
                    Prepares the property pointing to the JaCoCo runtime agent which
                    is passed as VM argument when Maven the Surefire plugin is executed.
                -->
                <execution>
                    <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                        <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
                        <!--
                            Sets the name of the property containing the settings
                            for JaCoCo runtime agent.
                        -->
                        <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <!--
                    Ensures that the code coverage report for unit tests is created after
                    unit tests have been run.
                -->
                <execution>
                    <id>post-unit-test</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                        <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</dataFile>
                        <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
                        <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.15</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>surefire-unit-tests</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Sets the VM argument line used when unit tests are run. -->
                        <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
                        <!-- Skips unit tests if the value of skip.unit.tests property is true -->
                        <skipTests>${skip.unit.tests}</skipTests>
                        <!-- Excludes integration tests when unit tests are run. -->
                        <skip>false</skip>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/*IntegrationTests.java</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.15</version>
            <executions>
                <!--
                    Ensures that both integration-test and verify goals of the Failsafe Maven
                    plugin are executed.
                -->
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-tests</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Sets the VM argument line used when integration tests are run. -->
                        <argLine>${failsafeArgLine}</argLine>
                        <!--
                            Skips integration tests if the value of skip.integration.tests property
                            is true
                        -->
                        <skipTests>${skip.integration.tests}</skipTests>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

And my jenkins configuration :

[image]

What is my error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a jenkins issue similar to my problem :

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28652

The error is caused by jacoco version.
The version 0.7.5.201505241946 is bugged. 
I switch for the version 0.7.4.201502262128 and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue and it is fixed by just updating the "jacoco-maven-plugin" version to 0.7.7.201606060606 and "maven-surefire-plugin" version to 2.19.1

I hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use in Jenkins Plugin :

Path to exec files  = **/**.exec

And I use this pom :

```
<jacoco.it.execution.data.file>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</jacoco.it.execution.data.file>
<jacoco.ut.execution.data.file>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</jacoco.ut.execution.data.file>

<plugin>
<groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
<artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>pre-integration-test</id>
        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <destFile>${jacoco.it.execution.data.file}</destFile>
            <propertyName>failsafeArgLine</propertyName>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
    <!-- Ensures that the code coverage report for integration tests after -->
    <!--  integration tests have been run. -->
    <execution>
        <id>post-integration-test</id>
        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>report-integration</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <dataFile>${jacoco.it.execution.data.file}</dataFile>
            <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-it</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: why you are doing : mvn clean install test, u can juste do :  mvn clean install

Comment: I do a "mvn clean install test" because the tutorial I use says "The command mvn clean test runs unit tests and creates the code coverage report for unit tests to the directory target/site/jacoco-ut".